# Images size "fitin=" HTML

Tags: html, css, image, size

I upload images to my shop's site at Rakuten. Rakuten was dedicated the images size to `128px` and my shop is using `255px` for every single image. The images that I upload are named as follow `"xxx.jpg?fitin=128:128"`.

I've changed it to `255px` and it works but the problem is that the images seem blurred. Can anybody help me fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try using object-fit:cover to your images

Answer (score 0):

Use **object-fit: cover;** 
It will cut off the sides of the image, preserving the aspect ratio, and also filling in the space.

```
img {
     object-fit: cover;
}
```